# Scrapy Xpath with text() contains

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy, and I'm trying to look for a span that contains a specific text. I have:

```
response.selector.xpath('//*[@class="ParamText"]/span/node()')
```

which returns:

```
<Selector xpath='//*[@class="ParamText"]/span/text()' data=u' MILES STODOLINK'>,
<Selector xpath='//*[@class="ParamText"]/span/text()' data=u'C'>,

<Selector xpath='//*[@class="ParamText"]/span/text()' data=u'  MILES STODOLINK'>]
```

However when I run:

```
>>> response.selector.xpath('//*[@class="ParamText"]/span[contains(text(),"STODOLINK")]')
Out[11]: []
```

Why does the contains function not work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`contains()` can not evaluate multiple nodes at once :

```
/span[contains(text(),"STODOLINK")]
```

So, in case there are multiple text nodes within the `span`, and `"STODOLINK"` isn't located in *the first text node child of the `span`*, then `contains()` in the above expression won't work. You should try to apply `contains()` check on individual text nodes as follow :

```
//*[@class="ParamText"]/span[text()[contains(.,"STODOLINK")]]
```

Or if `"STODOLINK"` isn't necessarily located directly within `span` (can be nested within other element in the `span`), then you can simply use `.` instead of `text()` :

```
//*[@class="ParamText"]/span[contains(.,"STODOLINK")]
```

Comment: Thank you, can I ask what '.' means here. I'm guessing 'any character' as in regex?

Comment: It is a reference to the element itself. As an aside, '..' is a reference to the element's parent; They work like in *nix systems (Linux, Mac, etc.) file paths, where '.' is the current directory and '..' is the parent directory.

Answer (score 2):

In my terminal (assuming my example is identical to your file though) your code works:

**Input**

```
import scrapy
example='<div class="ParamText"><span>STODOLINK</span></div>'
scrapy.Selector(text=example).xpath('//*[@class="ParamText"]/span[contains(text(),"STODOLINK")]').extract()
```

**Output:**

```
['<span>STODOLINK</span>']
```

Can you clarify what might be different?

Answer (score 2):

I use Scrapy with BeautifulSoup4.0. IMO, Soup is easy to read and understand. This is an option if you don't have to use HtmlXPathSelector. Below is an example for finding all links. You can replace that with 'span'. Hope this helps!

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import Item

def parse(self, response):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body,'html.parser')
    print 'Current url: %s' % response.url
    item = Item()
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if link.get('href') is not None:
            url = response.urljoin(link.get('href'))
            item['url'] = url
            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse)
            yield item
```